# EF6 Add-Migration in PowerShell, outside Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

How can I run the EF6 `Add-Migration` outside Visual Studio, in a PowerShell window?

When I try to run it, there is this error message:

```
Add-Migration : The term 'Add-Migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's a long time since you posted this. But have you managed to solve it?

Comment: No, I'm still stuck using it from Visual Studio

Comment: I have managed to load it in PS, but now I get this error: The term 'Get-Project' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: Hi! how did you manage to do it? @TheFreeman Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to ensure the module is loaded.  Because this is part of the VS environment from that console window, it loads some different modules by default.  You can resolve this by opening up your console in VS, and use

```
PS ~/> $path = (Get-Module -Name EntityFrameworkCore).Path
```

For me, this resolved to:

```
PS ~/> $path

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.1.1\tools\EntityFrameworkCore.psm1
```

So you can then take that path and import it in a regular powershell window:

```
PS ~/> Import-Module -Name $path
```

---

But after looking at the folder (which annoyingly doesn't follow standards), it also has a module manifest file (`.psd1`), which is what you *should* import instead:

```
PS ~/> Set-Location -Path 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.1.1\tools'
PS /Program Files/dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools/2.1.1/tools/> Import-Module -Name EntityFrameworkCore.psd1
```

---

Footnote: this is how my VS install initializes its console:

```
Import-Module 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\NUGET\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.psd1'
$__pc_args=@(); $input|%{$__pc_args+=$_}; & 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\2.1.1\tools\init.ps1' $__pc_args[0] $__pc_args[1] $__pc_args[2]; Remove-Variable __pc_args -Scope 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I could not import `EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psd1` (it is not EF Core but EF 6).
It said: 
Import-Module : The name of the current Windows PowerShell host is: 'ConsoleHost'. The module '...\Packages\
EntityFramework.6.2.0\tools\EntityFramework.psd1' requires the following Windows PowerShell host: 'Package Manager Host'.
It seems MS ensured these should only run from within VS...
I'm new to PowerShell. How could I renamed the PowerShell host?

Comment: You can either remove that line from the manifest or import the module file itself.

Comment: your answer is entirely about EFCore, however the question was about EF6..

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Microsoft.EntityFramework.Tools** of compatible version from NuGet Package Manager. That may solve your problem.